# how to run server using docker container?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Django server is running well in localhost. however, When I try to run server on the docker container, it doesn't find the manage.py file when using docker-compose file and even I run the container manually and run the server, it doesn't appear in browser. how can I solve this problem?

So I wrote all the code testing on my local server and using the dockerfile, I built the image of my project.

and I tried to run server on the docker container, suddenly this doesn't run.
what's worse, if I use docker-compose to run the server, it doesn't find the manage.py file though I already checked with 'docker run -it $image_name sh'

here is the code of my project

I am new to docker and new to programming.
hope you can give me a help. thanks!

file structure

```
current directory
└─example
└─db.sqlite3
└─docker-compose.yml
└─Dockerfile
└─manage.py
└─Pipfile
└─Pipfile.lock
```

Docker file

```
# Base image - Python version
FROM python:3.6-alpine

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /code

# Copy Pipfile
COPY Pipfile /code
COPY Pipfile.lock /code

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install pipenv
RUN pipenv install --system

# Copy files
COPY . /code/
```

docker-compose.yml

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

expected result : running server in web browser like in chrome

actual result :

- when using docker-compose : 
  ERROR like this in the prompt : web_1  | python: can't open file '/code/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
- when running the container manually with 'docker run -it $image_name sh' and 'python manage.py runserver' on the shell :
  server is running but, doesn't connect to web browser. (doesn't show up in browser like chrome'

Comment: I suspect your `/code` is a file. You should create the `/code` folder first and when copying to a folder end the destination with a slash.

Comment: When running manually with `docker run`, the server doesn't show up in browser because you have not `EXPOSE`ed the port.

Comment: why not change your command to "bash" instead of "manage.py runserver" and try and run it manually ... or at least check whats in /code

Comment: Simply add `-p 8000:8000` to expose the port in the `docker run` command. For unrelated reasons you also want `--rm` so as not to pollute your inventory with lots of abandoned instances.

Answer (score 1):

Yo have done same thing in many ways. You have copy source files using a `COPY` command and then you have mounted a host volume in your docker-compose.yml file. In first place you don't need a volume because volume mounts are to persisting data generated by and used by Docker containers.

Following simplified Dockerfile and docker-compose file would fix the problem.

```
# Base image - Python version
FROM python:3.6-alpine

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Copy files
COPY . /code/

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /code

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install pipenv
RUN pipenv install --system
```

docker-compose.yml -:

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

Comment: he probably doesnt need to set workdir at all since he is explicitly calling out the path to manage.py ... but really he should not be using manage.py runserver to actually serve for any real length of time(even inside a docker container)... but rather serve it behind nginx or apache ... I find that runserver becomes unresponsive after several days of light use

Comment: Yes, if you are using absolute path it would not be necessary. But in this case there will not be anything inside /code. As @JoranBeasley said removing the WORKDIR /code would work

Comment: yeah because of how hes doing it .. i think if he just does not use workdir at all it would properly mount his cwd to /code ... i think at least(+1 though because this seems likely to be the issue to me ... but im no docker pro :P )

Comment: The first paragraph is bogus. The `WORKDIR` doesn't affect the `COPY` command at all; it is using absolute paths within the container, so they are independent of any `WORKDIR`. Also, as per the quoted documentation, the `WORKDIR` will have the desirable side effect of creating the directory.